# Photoshop's like filters in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

My client wants to apply a filter (she has described it as the rough pastel filter in photoshop, but I'm fairly sure she really wanted some sort of a pencil sketched picture) to some pictures the users upload to the server. There is one limitation here: It needs to work with fairly any smartphone and computer (so no flash here. Such a pity). The good part is that   it can be entirely done on the server, without showing the resulting picture to the user (so it can be processed by external applications and it doesn't need to be "that fast").

The server is running linux and I'm sure I can install Imagemagick if it isn't already, and probably run other custom scripts (my client hasn't confirmed it yet), such as c++ applications or so. However, working with just PHP would be a plus, of course (I smell a shared server).

I won't ask anybody to code me a filter (of course, the client doesn't even know which she wants), but I'm actually asking if you think it's possible to do so, and if there is any wrapping library that does all the job or I need to do it by myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagemagick has quite a lot of filters etc. built in. I have an example of most of them on my site here: http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/operator.php

There is an API built into php called Imagick and I am working on some examples for it at the moment but it is a bit of a pain to use with minimal documentation.
This is an example of using the sketch operator in Imagick:

[image: Imagick sketchImage]

Imagick documentation for Above effect: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.sketchimage.php

In my Imagemagick examples I am using a grayscale version but it should be a similar result to the above image.

There are some filters using GD now but I have not tried them: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php

Comment: silly me! I definitely skipped that part when reading the imagemagick documentation. Well, thank you so much. By the way, your webpage is a panacea for those like me in need of some filters. Thank you for sharing it with us

Comment: I am glad you found my site useful; I started it a few years ago when I could not find any information about php and Imagemagick. I am trying to write an Imagick section at the moment. The main Imagemagick examples are here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/ and most of them can be modified to use php with exec()